# How to create view with foreign key table's columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a view for the main table. But this table contains more than one foreign key. I want to add these external tables' all matching rows to the main view.The structure is like that: [main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1me2L.png) [external table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tJBx.png) [external table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1w9q.png). And the view I want to create is that: [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYR9L.png). I have tried this PostgreSQL command but it doesn't work

```
CREATE VIEW main_table_view AS
SELECT * FROM main_table
INNER JOIN external_table1 ON "main_table_fkey1" = "external_table1_id"
INNER JOIN external_table2 ON "main_table_fkey2" = "external_table2_id"
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edirt you question

Comment: please don't post image. use dbfiddle setup the script. you code should work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d139c06dc3f160d5653652cd5ae9b41e

Comment: @jian thanks for your reply and advice. If there were more than 2 columns in extern_table1, how I can add only specific columns to view?

Comment: can you use dbfiddle uk create script and also explain what's the expected result.

Comment: @jian I want to select only specific columns. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d8bb75f8aa2c187a1599469950ded051

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=212546f5a608af3de0ac75ae24a7229f just select columns you want in the view.